# Closing a question with an open-bounty?

Tags: discussion

This question popped up recently: [IRB guidelines for secure online data storage, backup, and syncing?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26654/irb-guidelines-for-secure-online-data-storage-backup-and-syncing), which I personally believe is off-topic either because:

- This particular IRB has an official policy about data storage, in which case the question is very localised
- This particular IRB has no official policy about data storage, in which case the question is interesting, but becomes a secure data storage question, perhaps more adequate on security.SE.

Regardless of whether this question should be closed or not, I could not cast a vote, because there is an open-bounty on it. Is that a bug or a feature? I find it a bit weird that a question is "protected against closure" simply by adding a 50 rep bounty on it.

Answer (score 2):

The SE-recommended way to deal with a question with an open bounty that needs closure is to [flag for a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties).

You might leave a comment on the question to indicate you've done so, and that others who want to "cast close votes" should flag instead. If there are enough flags (indicating that the community wants to close the question), a moderator could refund the bounty and close the question.

Comment: Agree, but this still does not really explains *why* a simple 50 rep bounty protects a question against closing. Personally, I have no idea.